# How would I go about copying the JAR file to the startup directory? 

Tags: java, file, jar, copy, startup

I have the following methods at my disposal:

- A method to get the running JAR file's path. (The path of the file to copy).
- A method to get the current operating system. (Mac, Windows, Linux, or Unknown).

How would I go about writing a method to copy the JAR file to the startup directory based on the type of computer?

Comment: What's the definition of a start up directory?

Comment: The directory that opens up its contents when the computer starts up.

Comment: Somehow this question sounds like asking for a wrong way to do it.

Comment: Isn't this called `autostart`-dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a "startup directory" that you can drop executables into to run at startup time **does not make sense** for Linux / UNIX.

In a typical Linux system, tasks performed on system startup are controlled by the `init` process based on shell scripts that are typically installed in `/etc/init.d`.  The `chkconfig` program manages a bunch of links in "run level" directories that tell `init` what to run for each system run level.

The init.d scripts are not just any old script.

- They have to obey a specific "protocol"; i.e. support certain comman options.
- They typically have special comments that tell the `chkconfig` program when the script should be run; i.e. at what run levels, and in what order.

I believe that modern UNIX systems work roughly the same way, though I known that some older versions did this differently.

<sub>Update in 20012:  It gets worse. Recent Linux distros are replacing `init.d` scripts with `upstart` scripts.  Sigh.</sub>

---

The above deals with system startup.  There is no general concept of a "startup directory" for users either.

I guess, a window manager *could* implement a "startup directory", but a typical Linux user is free to choose and configure the window manager, or use no window manager at all.

The normal way to configure things to happen when the user logs in is via shell initialization scripts; e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_login` and so on.  It is a BAD IDEA for an installer to modify those files because it would be next to impossible to get it right in all circumstances ... given the weird and wonderful things it is possible to do in a shell initialization script.

---

The bottom line though is that if you are writing installers to install your software for a number of platforms, you have to understand those platforms.  You need hands on experience using them and (to some level) administering them, and specific knowledge of the "right way" to do software installation.  Clearly you don't have that knowledge yet for Linux / UNIX.

Writing installers without adequate knowledge and adequate testing is **really, really dangerous**.  An installer has to be run at a privilege level that means that it can do serious damage to the target system if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)'s FileUtils to copy the file (if you have the path and the name) to anywhere as long as you have permissions to write in destination.

Comment: I am aware of how to copy files. My problem is how to copy a JAR file and make it still runnable, and how to obtain the file paths of the startup directories on the following OS's: Windows, Mac, Linux.

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little better? Maybe there is a better way to accomplish what you want without having to deal with copying?

Comment: Okay. All I want to know is how to get the paths of the startup directory for a Windows computer, Mac, and Linux. All I need is a method that will return the string of the filepath of the startup directory and will include an if statement returning different paths depending on the OS.

Comment: Again, I have a method to get the current OS I just need help with a method to return the directory of the startup directory based on what OS the user is using.

Comment: I still dont understand the problem..I am so sorry. If you need to know the path of the current folder, then you can use System.getProperty("user.dir") or new File(".").getCanonicalPath()

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this question sounds like asking for a wrong way to do it. Why don't you start the jar from where it is - `java -jar /path/to/the/jar.jar` or `java -cp /path/the/jar.jar mainpackage.MainClass`

On **Linux**, the startup-dir - the dir, where you normally start , if you open a shell - is your `$HOME`, alias `/home/$USER`, or just the current directory `.` or `$(pwd)` or `$PWD` from there.

```
cp JARFILE $PWD
```

Would therefore copy the jar to the current dir, if nobody changed the starting dir. 
However, if you place a starter on the desktop, that might choose `$HOME/Desktop` as the startup-dir.

On Linux, there is no official startup-dir; nobody uses this expression.

We're talking about autostart?

If you want to run a program on the server, `/etc/init.d` might be the right place to put your program, or better a starting script for your program, which would go to `/usr/local/...` or `/opt/` or `/var`, depending on Linux flavour and user preferences.

If your program needs `X` (uses `awt/swing/swt`) it will need to wait for `X` to come up, then `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` would be the place to put the startscript.

Depending on resources it needs to run, there would be further considerations.

If it uses networking resources, and actions should be taken, depending on network start or shutdown, or on powermanagement, there are again different directories, to look for.

According with Stephen C., if you don't have any experience with Linux, you should give us much more information. What does your program do? Can we see it? Is it OpenSource? Which computer resources does it use? Client or server? GUI or console? Run by whom?

Comment: Okay. I REALLY do not understand. Can you or anyone give me some code that returns a string of the filepath to the startup directory of the computer.
Is that so hard to ask???

Comment: I've attempted to give an explanation of what Linux uses **instead of** a startup directory; see my answer.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337: From Stephen C's answer I understand, that you're speaking about an autostart-directory, are you? Then my post is invalid.